# Difficulty Proving a Function is Convex

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

I need to show that $J:C[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, defined by $J(x) = \int_0^1((x(t))^2-t^2x(t))dt$, is convex.

I try showing it is according to the definition of convexity. I get up this point

$$J(\lambda x+ (1-\lambda)y) = \lambda^2\int_0^1(x(t))^2dt + (1-\lambda)^2\int_0^1(y(t))^2dt + 2\lambda(1-\lambda)\int_0^1x(t)y(t)dt-\int_0^1t^2(\lambda x(t)+(1-\lambda)y(t))dt$$ and get lost as to where I can get some inqualities for desired result. Is there another better way to prove convexity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the terms $\lambda\int x^2,(1-\lambda)\int y^2$, these together with the last term is your goal. What left are the terms $-\lambda\int x^2+\lambda^2\int x^2$, $-(1-\lambda)\int y^2+(1-\lambda)^2\int y^2$ and $2\lambda(1-\lambda)\int xy$, its sum is then $-\lambda(1-\lambda)\int(x-y)^2$, which is non positive. Now you obtain the desired result.